# Вызвать метод активити из фрагмента

Tags: java, android

у меня есть активити с 3 фрагментами, и в самом активити есть метод налаживания связи и начала приёма данных с другого устройства. Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить метод активити из фрагмента так, чтобы при закрытии фрагмента метод продолжил работу(приём данных) а не приостановил её. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что происходит с активити во время закрытия фрагмента? если она не пересоздается и не останавливается, то ответ от Valeriy должен отработать как надо. Пример вызова был бы весьма кстати

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что именно вы хочете, возможно вам нужно обратить свой взор на сервисы, WorkManager или что-то инное... А запустить метод активности из фрагмента, при условии что именно в этой активности создан фрагмент, можно так:

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).yourMethod();

// или для Kotlin
activity?.let {
    (it as MyActivity).yourMothod()
}
```

Идея в следующем: ваш контекст, и есть вашей активностью.

Comment: в вашем примере при смене фрагмента метод прекратит выполняться, мне нужно, чтобы смена фрагмента не влияла на выполнение метода

Comment: вы для начала попробуйте, а потом утверждайте. Почему он прекратит выполнение? Вы делаете это через блокировку UI? У вас не сможет смениться фрагмент в априоре. Вы делаете в отдельном потоке, ему плевать после запуска кто и где, лиж бы получатель был жив. В третих выполнится в объекте из которой вы его вызвали, а там уже и создайте для него поле в котором вы его будете хранить и... Хотите, делайте через треды или вёрк менеджер или джоб скедуллер...

Comment: я пробовал, логи перестают идти при поступлении информации и смене фрагмента

Comment: Покажите как вы это делаете